# Images will not display horizontally (CSS)

Tags: css

`display:inline-block;` isn't doing the trick for me right now, not sure for what reason.

[Here's what I have as of right now](http://jsfiddle.net/aKNY4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
li{display:inline-block;}
```

**[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKNY4/3/)**. not only the images should be displayed as inline-block. their containers also need to be displayed side by side.